# Creating a 2d mesh in python

Tags: python, grid, matplotlib, mesh

I am really new to programming...

But here is my question :

I cannot post images but the plot I wish to have is a "crown" (two concentric circle with radius a
I mean, mathematically speaking is really easy to define but how can I do it with a python program ?

I thought of something like this :

```
def Fm1(X, Y):
    r =r = sqrt(1.*X**2+1.*Y**2)
    cos = 1.*X/r
    sin = 1.*Y/r
    teta = where( sin >= 0. , arccos(cos) , -arccos(cos) )
    teta = where(r == 0. , 0., teta)
    return r, teta


def F(r,teta):                                                                  
    X = r*cos(teta)                                                             
    Y = r*sin(teta)                                                             
    return X,Y
```

Those are simply the function that let you pass from the cartesian to the polar coordinates, and then :

```
r=sy.linspace(a,b,N+1) # radius division
t=sy.linspace(0,2.*pi,2**NN) #angle (theta) division
R,T=meshgrid(r,t) #creating a mesh

X,Y = F(R,T)#transform from polar to cartesian

#Plotting :
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)                                 
ax.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

But the result is : concentric polygons. I wish I had  N+1 circles at equidistance from radius a to radius b and 2**NN lines (origin center and a given angle).

Sorry I know it's really a trivial question,

Thanks

Comment: You use some functions I'm not familiar with. What are `where`, `ones`, `Fcm1`, `meshgrid`, and `Fc`?

Comment: Also, I'm having difficulty imagining the shape you're trying to draw. Wouldn't the outer and inner circles have different radiuses (radii?)? So wouldn't you need more than just `a` to define a crown?

Comment: @Kevin most of those are numpy functions, and I think the rest are typos.

Comment: I changed the code to what I first thought I should do. It is cleaner that way. Sorry. And yes you need two radius.

Comment: I added a tag for `matplotlib` and its subset functions `pylab`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my answers, I'll use **two libraries**:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
```

I believe these are the **constants** in your setup:

```
r_a = 0.50
r_b = 0.75
circles = 6  
lines   = 50
origin = (0, 0)
```

## Option 1: Plot directly

First, draw the **circles**:

```
for r in np.linspace(r_a, r_b, circles):
    pylab.gca().add_patch(pylab.Circle(origin, radius=r, 
                                       fill=False, color='black'))
```

Then draw the **lines**:

```
r_ab = np.array([r_a, r_b])
for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, lines):
    pylab.plot(np.cos(theta) * r_ab,
               np.sin(theta) * r_ab, color='red')
```

Finally, **display**:

```
pylab.axis('scaled')
pylab.show()
```

The **result**:

[image: Image of plot]

## Option 2: Plot segments:

(After importing the libraries, and setting the constants, as above.) First, compute the **point locations**:

```
r,t   = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(r_a, r_b, circles),
                    np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, lines))
x = r * np.cos(t)
y = r * np.sin(t)
```

Then **plot the circles** (as you do) and **plot the lines**

```
# Plot circles
pylab.plot(x, y)
# Plot lines (first and last x and y of each theta)
pylab.plot(np.vstack((x[:,0], x[:, -1])),
           np.vstack((y[:,0], y[:, -1])))
```

Finally, **display**:

```
pylab.axis('scaled')
pylab.show()
```

The **result**:

[image: Second option result]

**Note**:
After all this, I think all you really needed was the last bit in Option 2 about plotting the lines. I'll keep all this other answer stuff here for any future readers.

Comment: Almost ! the lines should start at the intersection with the circle with radius r_a. So for the lines it would be something like this :
    `for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, lines):
        pylab.plot(( np.cos(theta) * r_a , np.cos(theta) * r),
               ( np.sin(theta) * r_a, np.sin(theta) * r), 'red')`

Comment: But my main problem is not to actually make the figure but to have a mesh with those points (so I guess the matrix I described in my post would be alright) and to verify which points I had I wanted to have the graphic that you showed ! So is it possible that from a matrix (with all the grid points) have a figure like yours above ?

Comment: I updated my picture, and code to show the wheel as you indicated in your first comment. From your second comment, I'm still not clear on what you want. You're correctly sub-sampling a bunch of concentric circles. Is the problem that the line-segments connecting your points are straight, and not fit to the circle? Plotting a mesh will always result in straight lines.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you ! :) As the Jacobian matrix of the transformation has a singular point in the origin I needed to have a grid with 2 patches so this is the external patch. I now have my running program with both patches so thank you !

Comment: Great. Glad it's what you needed.